# Random subset of a fixed set in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose that you have a set A in Julia. How do you generate a random subset from A?
Is there any package or special function to do this?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best method I can think of for sampling without replacement is to use the `sample` method from StatsBase ([Doc](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/sampling/#Sampling-from-Population-1)). [Unfortunately, this method currently only works for indexable collections.](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/issues/402) So you would have to convert your Set to an Array first and your sample back to Set.

```
using StatsBase

A = Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
S = Set(sample(collect(A), 3, replace = false))
```